# Notify Property Changed Event without setter

Tags: c#, wpf, mvvm

I am developing a WPF application using MVVM architect, and as a common scenario using properites to Notify Changes like

```
public List<EmployeeInfo> Employees
    {
            get
            {
                return _employees;
            }
            set
            {
                _employees = value;
                NotifyPropertyChanged(() => Employees);
            }
        }
```

My only issue is that i am using property setter to notify application about the changes made to some value, and according to FxCop this is a bad practice and `'CollectionPropertiesShouldBeReadOnly'`. So i want to improve a little bit on that, so tell me some mechanism with which i could use Notify Property changed without using setter.

Comment: ObservableCollection itself has support for notifying changes why do you need to add your own here?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

If your collection property is read-only, you don't need to notify anything that the entire collection has changed to a different one - instead, the event handlers *on the collection* will be notified of changes within the collection (the addition of items etc).

If you need to be able to change which collection the property refers to within the view model, you could always make the setter *private* and keep the existing notification mechanism.

Comment: My collection property is not readonly, but i dont want to write setter for it, user could add or remove anything directly from it, i just want that it'll notify me, whenever it happens and please don't expect it to be Observable collection always, it could be anything List, IEnumerable, dictionary etc. Thanks

Comment: @MSingh: Well that makes a *huge* difference - if it's a `List<T>` then there *is* no notification mechanism. That's the whole *point* of `ObservableCollection<T>`. It sounds like you're not clear in your mind on the difference between a read-only *property* (one without a setter) and an immutable *collection* (one whose contents can't be changed). It sounds like you only need a read-only property, but returning a mutable (changable) collection. If you want that collection to notify listeners, you *must* use `ObservableCollection<T>` or something very similar.

Comment: Yes, i was little confused about these scenarios, but thanks for your help. Thanks a Lot

Answer (score 0):

The ObservableCollection itself informs about changes happened. So you don't need to raise the PropertyChanged Event. If you think, that it's necessary tho change the collection, then you can delete and add items. Due to the observable pattern, the changes will be anounced.

Answer (score 0):

The fact that you are using a setter means you're trying to replace the instance of the collection with a new object instance.  If you just are worried about changes to items in the collection, that's already built into the observablecollection.  FxCop is going to complain about the setter whether you had the notifypropertychanges call or not.