# Binding in radiobutton not working c# uwp

Tags: c#, data-binding, binding, uwp

I have a radio button and currently binded to my Application's property. I added breakpoint in the `set` part of the accessor and can't seem to hit it after clicking the radio button.

Also:
I have checked other links from SO but they only show the xaml part and the converter implementation. I haven't seen the source files fully implemented.

*XAML.CS*

```
public sealed partial class MainPage : Page
{
    public CustomConverter c = new CustomConverter();
    MyModel model = new MyModel();

    public MainPage()
    {
        this.InitializeComponent();
        this.DataContext = model;
    }
}
```

*XAML*

```
    <StackPanel>
        <StackPanel.Resources>
            <local:CustomConverter x:Key="customConverter"/>
        </StackPanel.Resources>
            <RadioButton HorizontalAlignment="Left" VerticalAlignment="Top" Margin="100,100"
                 IsChecked="{Binding model.Number, Converter={StaticResource customConverter}, Mode=TwoWay}" Content="hello"/>
    </StackPanel>
```

*Converter and Model*

```
using System;
using System.Collections.Generic;
using System.Linq;
using System.Text;
using System.Threading.Tasks;
using Windows.UI.Xaml.Data;

namespace DataBindingTest
{
    public class MyModel
    {
        private int number;
        public int Number
        {
            get { return this.number; }
            set
            {
                this.number = value; **//ADDED A BREAKPOINT HERE**
            }
        }
    }

    public class CustomConverter : IValueConverter
    {
        public object Convert(object value, Type targetType,
            object parameter, string language)
        { 
            return false;
        }

        // No need to implement converting back on a one-way binding 
        public object ConvertBack(object value, Type targetType,
            object parameter, string language)
        {
            return null;
        }
    }
}
```

Comment: You haven't set the data binding yet. The view's DataContext property is still empty.

Comment: Possible duplicate of [Notify Property Changed Event without setter](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/7871752/notify-property-changed-event-without-setter)

Comment: @lindexi that question doesn't solve my question

Comment: @kennyzx added the DataContext but still not working

Comment: Broken logic between `Mode=TwoWay` and `// No need to implement converting back on a one-way binding`. If you want help with a specific problem, please be very careful to write a question that doesn't contain other (potential) problems.

Comment: Bind to the property Number, not model.Number. And the MyModel class needs to implement INotifyPropertyChange interface.